# Discord Bot Cannot read property 'size' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

**Discord Bot[discord.js V 12]**

```js
async execute(client,message,args,dbl,queue,messagecounter) {
  const Discord = require('discord.js')

    const embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .addFields(
    {name: 'Connected Users', value: message.guild.me.voice.channel.members.cache.size, inline: true})
     message.channel.send(embed1)
};
```

Please Help me how to fix this error
**Error:**

`Cannot read property 'size' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error is originating from this line:

`message.guild.me.voice.channel.members.cache.size`

You should probably check to make sure you are passing in a message object with the properties you are accessing. If you are using an object with properties you are not certain about you should check to see if the property exists, and if it doesn't set it to some default value.

Answer (score -1):

```
message.channel.send({embeds:[embed1]})
```

Comment: Care for some more explanation?

Comment: This is not an answer. Does it have anything to do with the question? How does it solve the error message? How does this make `members.cache` not `undefined`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33649856)